# Java SOCKS proxy

Tags: java, proxy, socks

Does the socksProxyHost property require an IP address?

```
System.setProperty("socksProxyHost", preferences.getProxyHost() );
```

Setting it like above, if I provide 127.0.0.1, I get connected to the proxy on my localhost. But if I provide localhost, it does not connect it. I have no other machines on the LAN I can use to this. So does anyone know if it works with hosts names or do I have to resolve the host and pass in an IP?

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but have you ensured that your machine resolves localhost correctly outside of java?  At the CLI?

Answer (score 2):

System properties are just a dumb map. There are no observers to be notified when a value changes. It is normal to read a value just once and store it in a `private static final`, rather than looking the value up every time that it is needed.

Probably the relevant code is initialised whilst loading your application, so the value has already been read. A quick look at the API docs shows a promising method to call to change the default proxy: [`ProxySelector.setDefault`](http://file:///C:/Users/tackline/sun/docs/api/java/net/ProxySelector.html#setDefault(java.net.ProxySelector)).