# How to connect to a SOCKS proxy in a java applet

Tags: java, proxy, socks

I've made a Java applet that accesses a webpage. I need it to connect to a website via a SOCKS proxy I've already tried putting this code where my program initialises:

```
System.setProperty("socksProxyHost", "66.85.144.228");
System.setProperty("socksProxyPort", "1080");
```

But nothing seems to happen and it just uses my normal IP address?

Comment: Are you sure you can set it for an applet?  That seems like something that would require a signed applet (it also seems like something that should be handled by the browser, but that might make too much sense)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your properties might be [being set too-late](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948535/java-socks-proxy), after they have already been read by the relevant code when it initializes, but you are also probably hitting the [security restrictions of a sandboxed applet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html).  Is your applet signed, or is it running sandboxed?

If this were a Java Application rather than an applet, you could test this by setting these on your JVM launch e.g. `"-DsocksProxyHost=66.85.144.228 -DsocksProxyPort=1080"`.

Since you are working with an applet, there are restrictions on what system properties you can set.  You can [set deployment parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/applet_dev_guide.html#A1149935):

```
<APPLET archive="my_applet.jar" code="MyApplet" width="300" height="300">
    <PARAM name="java_arguments" value="-DsocksProxyHost=66.85.144.228">
</APPLET>
```

... however `socksProxyHost` is of course not in the [list of trusted/secure properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources), so your applet would need to be completely signed to be runnable.

Comment: How exactly would you set a JVM command-line property in an applet?

Comment: Excellent comment! Updated with applet-specific notes.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it programmatically via `java.net.Proxy.`

Comment: Not the downvoter, but your answer doesn't explain how to use java.net.Proxy programmatically to solve the problem...

Comment: @ericbn That is explained in the normal place, in the Javadoc. There's nothing in the question that suggests the OP wants to be spoonfed.